# Separate control of a loop pedal without effecting the main sound

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal

For instance I have a guitar a loop pedal, a distortion pedal, and a volume pedal. Well what I want to get is:

While playing, to be able to increase or decrease the volume of the loop pedal without effecting the solo played over the loop that is effected only by the distortion pedal.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling the loop volume with your volume pedal without affecting the signal is not really possible with only those three pedals in your pedalboard.

If you have the loop already going, placing the volume pedal before the loop would only allow you to alter the sound played over the loop. Placing the volume after the loop would affect both at the same time.

One option, assuming no other pedals and not touching the loop pedal knobs, would be to do the opposite: instead of lowering the volume of the loop, get a boost on the solo after recording the loop by placing the volume before the loop and altering the solo sound without affecting the looped sound.

Comment: I need tp change the loop volume 'during playing solo.

Comment: this is absolutely doable, but as Joncour says, not with what you have.